# Error converting a pandas dataframe to a geodataframe - : x and y arrays must be equal length

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

With a huge Pandas dataframe, `'pc'`:

```
pc.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1754851 entries, 0 to 1754850
Data columns (total 33 columns):
 #   Column                          Dtype  
---  ------                          -----  
 0   Latitude                        float64
 1   Longitude                       float64
 2   Easting                         Int64  
 3   Northing                        Int64  
 4   Grid Ref                        string 
 5   County                          string 
 6   District                        string 
 7   Ward                            string 
 8   Country                         string 
 9   Constituency                    string 
 10  Parish                          string 
 11  National Park                   string 
 12  Population                      Int64  
 13  Households                      Int64  
 14  Built up area                   string 
 15  Built up sub-division           string 
 16  Lower layer super output area   string 
 17  Rural/urban                     string 
 18  Region                          string 
 19  Altitude                        Int64  
 20  London zone                     string 
 21  Local authority                 string 
 22  Middle layer super output area  string 
 23  Index of Multiple Deprivation   string 
 24  Quality                         Int64  
 25  User Type                       Int64  
 26  Last updated                    string 
 27  Nearest station                 string 
 28  Distance to station             float64
 29  Police force                    string 
 30  Water company                   string 
 31  Plus Code                       string 
 32  Average Income                  Int64  
dtypes: Int64(8), float64(3), string(22)
memory usage: 455.2 MB
```

having a column named `'Latitude'` and another named `'Longitude'`, I have attempted to form a Geopandas geodataframe thus:

```
gdfpc = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(pc, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(pc.Longitude, df.Latitude))
```

This has led to the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal length.
```

Calling `pc.head()` and `pc.tail()` doesn't help:

```
pc.head()
    Latitude  Longitude  Easting  ...   Water company    Plus Code Average Income
0  57.149606  -2.096916   394235  ...  Scottish Water  9C9V4WX3+R6           <NA>
1  57.148707  -2.097806   394181  ...  Scottish Water  9C9V4WX2+FV           <NA>
2  57.149051  -2.097004   394230  ...  Scottish Water  9C9V4WX3+J5           <NA>
3  57.148080  -2.094664   394371  ...  Scottish Water  9C9V4WX4+64           <NA>
4  57.150058  -2.095916   394296  ...  Scottish Water  9C9V5W23+2J           <NA>
[5 rows x 33 columns]
pc.tail()
          Latitude  Longitude  ...    Plus Code  Average Income
1754846  59.889544  -1.307206  ...  9CFWVMQV+R4            <NA>
1754847  59.873651  -1.305697  ...  9CFWVMFV+FP            <NA>
1754848  59.875286  -1.307502  ...  9CFWVMGR+4X            <NA>
1754849  59.891572  -1.313847  ...  9CFWVMRP+JF            <NA>
1754850  59.892392  -1.310899  ...  9CFWVMRQ+XJ            <NA>
[5 rows x 33 columns]
```

Looking for the largest and smallest of Latitude and Longitude has not identified missing values which might have given a clue:

```
pc.nlargest(1, columns='Latitude')
          Latitude  Longitude  ...    Plus Code  Average Income
1754598  60.800694  -0.869518  ...  9CGXR42J+75            <NA>
[1 rows x 33 columns]
pc.nlargest(1, columns='Longitude')
         Latitude   Longitude  Easting  ...  Water company Plus Code Average Income
111540   4.610106  114.331172     <NA>  ...           <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
[1 rows x 33 columns]
pc.nsmallest(1, columns='Latitude')
         Latitude  Longitude  Easting  ...  Water company Plus Code Average Income
111552 -51.796253 -59.523613     <NA>  ...           <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
[1 rows x 33 columns]
pc.nsmallest(1, columns='Longitude')
         Latitude   Longitude  Easting  ...  Water company Plus Code Average Income
111544  34.924031 -117.891208     <NA>  ...           <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
[1 rows x 33 columns]
```

Converting the respective columns into individual Pandas series and then into numpy arrays for further analysis still fails to unearth any discernable difference:

```
>>>La = pc['Latitude']
>>>Lo = pc['Longitude']
>>>npLa=La.to_numpy(copy=True)
>>>npLo=Lo.to_numpy(copy=True)
>>>np.asarray(npLo).shape
(1754851,)
>>>np.asarray(npLa).shape
(1754851,)
>>>npLa.size
1754851
>>>npLo.size
1754851
```

Any ideas before I resign myself to using Haversine formulae all over the place?

Comment: You are referencing *two* different dataframes (pc, df) in this line: `gdfpc = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(pc, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(pc.Longitude, df.Latitude))`. Is this a typo or wanted?

Comment: Was it a typo here in your post or in your actual code? If the latter, does fixing the typo fix your problem? Then you should remove this question, IMO.

Comment: It was a typo but I do not have the ability to delete it - if you do, feel free